# Select to the sentence of line in a shortcut

Tags: region, mark, point, sentences

`C-k` and `M-k` could delete forward to the end of line and sentence respectively.

How could only select to the end in a shortcut?

Usually select a sentence and append it to a file for further reference with the following code:

```
;; Captrue words
(require 'thingatpt)

(defun my-append-word ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((word (if (not (region-active-p))
                  (word-at-point)
                (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end)))))
    (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/src/build-vocabulary.org")
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert word "\n")
      (save-buffer))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command `mark-end-of-sentence` does what you request. It's not bound to a key by default, but you can bind it to one. `C-h f mark-end-of-sentence` tells you:

> **`mark-end-of-sentence`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `paragraphs.el`.
>
> `(mark-end-of-sentence ARG)`
>
> Put mark at end of sentence.  Arg works as in `forward-sentence`.
>
> If this command is repeated, it marks the next `ARG` sentences after the
>   ones already marked.

---

You can find this command by asking `apropos-command` (`C-h a`) for commands related to "mark" and "sentence": `C-h a mark sentence`.

Commands that select text often have the word `mark` in their names, as selecting is about setting the mark at one end of the thing you're selecting (the end opposite point).

---

Library [Thing-At-Point Commands](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ThingAtPointCommands) ([`thing-cmds.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/thing-cmds.el)) has generic command **`select-things`** (aliased to the name `mark-things`), to select successive THINGs of any kind that has an associated `forward-THING` command.

If the region isn't active then you're prompted for the type of THING to use.

If the region is active, you aren't prompted, and the last-used type of THING is used again. On consecutive uses of `mark-thing`, the region is active, so you aren't prompted, and the region is extended to successive things of the same type.

This is true even if the region is empty, so you can just hit `C-SPC` to set mark and activate an empty region, then use `mark-thing` to select successive things of the last type used.

Command `thgcmd-bind-keys` (interactively or in your init file) binds `C-M-SPC` to `select-things`. (Vanilla Emacs binds `C-M-SPC` to `mark-sexp`.)

Comment: Please consider accepting @xuchunyang's answer. I think it's generally better than mine, which ignored your request of selection to end-of-line.

Answer (score 1):

Use `S-C-e` and `S-M-e`, that is holding Shift while typing `C-e` and `M-e`, see [(emacs) Shift Selection](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shift-Selection.html).

Comment: @Drew M-e moves to end of current sentence.

Comment: S-C-e and S-M-e are C-k and M-k's counterparts.