# What's the rules to bind keys

Tags: key-bindings

I learn the `mark-end-of-sentence` is handy to select to end of the sentence as handy as C-M-Space which select a word.
from [Select to the sentence of line in a shortcut](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54722/select-to-the-sentence-of-line-in-a-shortcut)

The function is not bound by default, so I tried kinds of keys permutations.

- one option is C-M-s (s for sentence) and C-M corresponding to C-M-Space to select a word, then faild.

  `(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-s") #'mark-end-of-sentence)`

[global-set-key (kbd “C-M-s”) 'mark-end-of-sentence](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54759/global-set-key-kbd-c-m-s-mark-end-of-sentence)

- It remind me that M-e move-forward to end of a sentence, then set 'C-M-e`which cover the original`(sp-end-of-sexp &optional ARG)`, still failed.

  `(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-s") #'mark-end-of-sentence)`
- Final solution, I set a key sequence randomly.

Take it seriously, what's the rules to bind keys? Two items I could get:

1. Not conflict with the current important and frequent keys
2. as semantic as possible to assistance memory.

I am determined passing my emacs.config to the grandsons, how could I play a intelligent role from now?

Comment: Not rules, rather some conventions are defined [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html).

Comment: The question is rambling, and not very clear. Could you please clarify/simplify it?

Comment: In particular, specify what you mean by "failed", and show the code you tried, which "failed".

Comment: question revised @Drew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html) referenced in a comment on the question,

> Sequences consisting of `C-c` and a letter (either upper or lower case) are reserved for users; they are the **only** sequences reserved for users, so do not block them.

So as a user, you redefine arbitrary keys outside of that range at your own risk, though of course people do it all the time.

Recently as I work on my config I've been trying to go back to original conventions as much as possible. For example, one of the first things in my first .emacs in 1995 was to bind `query-replace-regexp` to M-s (instead of M-%), but I've just turned it back to M-%. It's still customized because I want regexp by default instead of regular, but it follows the convention so is more portable, easier to talk to others about, less likely to conflict with functionality added in the future, etc.

For what bindings I do add, I have been trying to use custom prefix maps as a way to get unconstrained namespaces. Relevant to your example about commands to mark things, I have a "mark-map" to support different functions to mark text objects. Of course you still need to bind the map to some prefix key, and maybe C-M-SPC would be a good choice, so `mark-word` would become C-M-SPC w. Or if you wanted to be more standards compliant you could use C-c m. Or I think meta-capital-letter combinations are overlooked; how about M-M (shift-meta-m)?

```
(defvar mark-text-object-map (make-sparse-keymap)
  "Keymap for selecting text objects")
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-SPC") mark-text-object-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-@") mark-text-object-map) ;; How C-M-SPC shows up in some terminals
(define-key mark-text-object-map (kbd "b") #'mark-whole-buffer)
(define-key mark-text-object-map (kbd "w") #'mark-word)
(define-key mark-text-object-map (kbd "s") #'mark-end-of-sentence)
...
;; get a listing of the available commands
(define-key mark-text-object-map (kbd "?")
    #'(lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (with-help-window (help-buffer)
          (with-current-buffer (help-buffer)
            (insert (substitute-command-keys "\\{mark-text-object-map}"))))))
```

All that said, binding new keys isn't everything. Decomposition can be a good strategy. Sometimes it's easier to do C-SPC M-f, or C-SPC M-e, than it is to bind and use a dedicated command :)